# Privacy on XBox Live

Tags: xbox-360

So, my boss is awesome.  He is super nice and a really good boss to boot.

Today we happened to be discussing XBox gaming and found that we currently like the same game (Black Ops).

So we did what any normal gamers would do and exchanged gamer tags.

Now, I am looking forward to playing online with my boss.  But at the same time I am a bit worried.

I sometimes play during lunch (I work at home some days) and I would not want his family (whom he shares the XBox with) saying "Vaccano was online during work today".  (My boss may not care, but I don't want that stigma.)

Is there any way to easily hide when I am online and when I am not?  (Note, I don't always want to hide that I am online or I will miss out on game invites.)

Comment: What a tangled web we weave...
Seriously, the world will be a better place when people stop hiding things from each other.

Comment: @Sparr - Actually, I am not trying to hide.  I am trying to avoid misunderstanding.  It is totally OK for me to play XBox during my lunch break (or go to the store, or go get food or whatever).  However, if his family (off for Christmas break) reports that I was online playing "during the day" then it will look bad.  I doubt my boss would ever confront me so I could explain.  So it would just hang out there as a stigma on me (not what I want)

Comment: @Vaccano I simply choose not to work for people like that. You should, too.

Comment: @Vaccano also, you have an odd definition of "hide" if what you want to do is not hiding.

Comment: @Sparr - you are totally misunderstanding.  My boss would not care at all that I play during lunch.  He is a fantastic boss who is great to work for.  Re-read what I have written with this in mind and you will see what I am trying to say.

Comment: @Vaccano then I'm confused, who do you think is going to hold this stigma against you?

Comment: @Sparr - the worry is that he will think that I am playing during non-lunch hours.  Unless his family is very specific ("he was on from 12:04 to 1:00") he will not know when I was playing.  As I doubt they will be that specific, I just want to avoid the possibility of confusion.  (All of this is just me being careful.  Most likely none of this would ever matter at all.)

Comment: @Vaccano is "Hey boss, I'll be playing on XBox Live during my lunch breaks" not a solution to this nonproblem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to bring up the mini dash (with the guide).
Setttings page-> Preferences->Online Status->Appear Offline. This is also where you change it back to Online, Away, or Busy.
[Youtube Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9V6390j5os)

If I'm 'sick' from class I usually unplug my ethernet cable first, sign in with my profile, change my status to offline, and then connect to live. I'm pretty sure this stops it from showing up as signed in X hours ago.

Answer (score 8):

There is an option to set yourself invisible.

Guide > Settings > Preferences > Online Status > Appear Offline

You cannot set yourself offline to just one person, it would have to be to your whole friends list. Once you do want to appear online set it to Online.

Also note, if your Gamer Tag auto signs on when you start your X-Box you might want to unhook your Ethernet cable. Once you set your status to offline then you can plug it back in and play online without being detected by your boss.